# How to redirect to admin login page in mvc internet application template? (by defaut, it redirect to account/login page))

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

1. I have login page in user site and adminlogin page in admin site
2. I have action

   [Authorize]
   public ActionResult ChangeProfile(User model)
   {
       // my code
   }

and action in admin site

```
 [Authorize(Roles="Admins")]
    public ActionResult UserManager(User model)
    {
      // my code
    }
```

I like when i access to action ChangeProfile => redirect to login page in user site (if not login)
and when i access to action UserManager => redirect to adminlogin page in admin site (if not login with Admins roles)
Please help me to show me what could i do, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`.

```
public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        else
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new 
               RouteValueDictionary("Admin login route"));
    }
}

[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Admins")]
public ActionResult UserManager(User model)
{
    // my code
}
```

If you have something like this in your web.config file:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
```

change it to this but i'm not really sure it works or not but you can try:

```
<forms loginUrl="/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
```

Comment: Just one more thing, when i login in successful with users roles, after that i access to admin areas, it not redirect to admin login page, it's redirected to login page in user site, Please help me to fix it, thanks..